# Turning pairs of bytes into floats

Tags: c#

Anyone have something equivalent to (and prettier than) the following code?

```
private static float[] PairsOfBytesToFloats(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes.Length.IsNotAMultipleOf(2)) throw new ArgumentException();

    float[] result = new float[bytes.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
    {
        result[i / 2] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `BitConverter.ToUInt16`? Maybe `BitConverter.ToSingle`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of LINQ:

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length/2)
    .Select(index => (float)BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, index*2))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of loop:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, result, 0, bytes.Length);
```